# Do I need to enter USA every year in order to keep my B1/B2 visa valid?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I have a ten-year visitor business B1-B2 visa that I got 2 years ago. I haven't been in the US since that time. Am I allowed to go in 2017? I hear that I should go every year for the visa to stay valid.

Answer (score 10):

> I hear that I should go every year for the visa to stay valid.

There is no such thing. The visa is valid up until the expiration date. You can refrain from using it until the day it expires and enter the US on that day if you wanted to, and it would be valid.

Comment: The only catch is that if you're a Chinese citizen, you need to update your information in [EVUS](https://www.evus.gov/evus/#/) online every two years (this may be expanded to other citizenships in the future). Still no need to go to the US every year though.

Comment: @Zach Lipton what happens if you fail to update your information within 2 years. Let's say a visitor obtains a visa in 2017 and travels after updating his EVUS. He never updates his EVUS until 2022 when he decides to travel the the USA again. Can he travel on the same visa or will his visa have been revoked?

Comment: @greatone My understanding, based on [the FAQ](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/electronic-visa-update-system-evus/frequently-asked-questions) is that it's like the ESTA system: you have to have an up-to-date record in EVUS for the airline to let you board. If you wait five years between trips to the US (or get a new passport), you just have to make sure you do it before your next trip (72 hours in advance to be safe, though it's usually instantaneous). I've never seen anything that indicates a visa would be revoked under such circumstances.